# How to return value if a number is withing a specified range in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to return a value (1,2,3,4 or 5) based on the range a number falls in. I want to define a function and apply the function to a column in a DataFrame using `.apply()`.

In the code below, `amount` is a hypothetical column in a DataFrame. However, I get the error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` on line `elif >= 40 amount < 60:` (I believe it will raise the same error on all other lines).

```
amount = pd.Series([20, 25, 65, 80])

def miles(amount):
    if 20 >= amount < 40:
        return 1
    elif >= 40 amount < 60:
        return 2
    elif >= 60 amount < 80:
        return 3
    elif >= 80 amount < 100:
        return 4
    elif >= 100 amount < 120:
        return 5
    else:
        pass
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: use `pandas.cut`, not your function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this particular case, you are mapping discrete fixed-width integer ranges to a number.  This can be solved using a linear transform. The offset in this case is 0.

```
amount = pd.Series([20, 25, 65, 80])
out = amount.divide(20).astype(int)
out
# returns:
0   1
1   1
2   3
3   4
dtype: int32
```

For a more general case where the binning is not fixed-width, you can use `pd.cut`.

```
pd.cut(amount, [20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120], right=False, labels=[1,2,3,4,5]).astype(int)
# returns:
0   1
1   1
2   3
3   4
dtype: int32
```

Comment: Thank you very much James for providing two easy ways of solving this!

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
pd.cut(amount, range(20,121,20), labels = range(1,6), right = False)
#Output:
#0    1
#1    1
#2    3
#3    4
#dtype: category
#Categories (5, int64): [1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5]
```

The first argument is the `pandas.Series` you want to cut, the next one are the bins, `labels` associates every bin with a label, and `right` includes the rightmost edge of the bin when it's `True`.

---

For more details check the documentation: [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas.cut to do this.

It will separate your array elements into different sections.

Here is a link to the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html

Hopefully this helps :)